# Is there a significant difference in production costs for Live Action vs animated OP/ED?

Tags: anime-production, desert-punk

With the anime *Desert Punk* despite the fact that the anime is animated, the Opening is in fact live action. To me this seems kind of odd.

So, I am wondering if there are any other anime which are animated yet use Live Action Openings/Endings, and if it's significantly cheaper or more expensive to produce a Live Action OP/ED rather than doing an animated one.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've seen a few (older) series (_Puni Puni Poemi_, _The Irresponsible Captain Tylor_) where _part_ of the OP/ED uses live action footage, but none that are fully live action.

Comment: I decided to delete my answer because it seems I had some information wrong about the costs of live-action vs animation. The two are actually fairly comparable in price, I've learned. I don't know where or how I got the idea that live-action was cheaper, but at least while going through this whole process, I myself learned something along the way. Hopefully someone else can help give a better (and correct) answer! Sorry.

Comment: I remember that air gear had a live action ending. But I think it was more because at the time doing a smooth action animated was really harder (if you watch the series there was few images) so for the kind of story it had, you had a better feeling of liberty with a live action ending.
So at the end I think it comes more from the kind of anime it is and the personal taste of the persons doing those openings/endings :)